# Windows 7 halts booting when Apple Keyboard connected

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios

When Windows 7(64bit) is booting, and Apple Keyboard is connected by USB, then it halts on 'Vaio' logo, while loading BIOS(and I have to disconnect keyboard, restart computer, and connect when windows has loaded).Also- if I connect it after bios has loaded, when windows is showing it's logo 'starting'- it halts too. I have Sony VAIO, and bios is from American Megatrends.

What can be the explanation of such strange behaviour?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it in the bios to Halt On: No errors. Basically you want it to not Halt on keyboard errors.

Comment: Bios setup is soo poor- I can only set boot devices' order. I've noticed, that when I connect keyboard when windows is loading, it also halts.